# ProxySQL in kubernetes cluster dumps servers

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, proxysql

I manage a kubernetes cluster where I just recently added a ProxySQL to handle the query routing between the Master and Read-Replica. In the beginning it seemed to work well but after a few days it crashes when it recieves high traffic. Causing more than 30mins of downtime and I do not have the expertise to figure out why this happens. The Master and Read-Replica is hosted at Google and it's a Mysql 8.0.

ProxySQL log when the crash happened:
[image: ProxySQL log]

ProxySQL log when it came up again:
[image: ProxySQL log up again]

The docker image I'm using: severalnines/proxysql:1.4.12
With the configuration:

```html
datadir="/var/lib/proxysql"

admin_variables=
{
    admin_credentials="USER:PASS"
    mysql_ifaces="0.0.0.0:6032"
    refresh_interval=2000
}

mysql_variables=
{
    threads=4
    max_connections=2048
    default_query_delay=0
    default_query_timeout=36000000
    have_compress=true
    poll_timeout=2000
    interfaces="0.0.0.0:6033"
    default_schema="information_schema"
    stacksize=1048576
    server_version="8.0"
    connect_timeout_server=10000
    monitor_history=60000
    monitor_connect_interval=200000
    monitor_ping_interval=200000
    ping_interval_server_msec=10000
    ping_timeout_server=200
    commands_stats=true
    sessions_sort=true
    monitor_username="USER"
    monitor_password="PASS"
}

mysql_replication_hostgroups =
(
    { writer_hostgroup=10, reader_hostgroup=20, comment="MySQL Replication 8.0" }
)

mysql_servers =
(
    { address="10.32.224.4", port=3306, hostgroup=10, max_connections=100 }, # MASTER
    { address="10.32.224.4", port=3306, hostgroup=20, max_connections=100 }, # MASTER
    { address="10.32.224.44", port=3306, hostgroup=20, max_connections=100, weight=10, max_replication_lag=5} # REPLICA
)

mysql_users =
(
    { username = "USER", password = "PASS", default_hostgroup = 10, active = 1 },
    { username = "USER", password = "PASS", default_hostgroup = 10, active = 1 },
    { username = "USER", password = "PASS", default_hostgroup = 10, active = 1 }
)

mysql_query_rules =
(
    {
        rule_id=100
        active=1
        match_pattern="^SELECT .* FOR UPDATE"
        destination_hostgroup=10
        apply=1
    },
    {
        rule_id=200
        active=1
        match_pattern="^SELECT .*"
        destination_hostgroup=20
        apply=1
    },
    {
        rule_id=300
        active=1
        match_pattern=".*"
        destination_hostgroup=10
        apply=1
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you explain us a little bit more about your GKE set up? 
Also, as per the [ProxySQL documentation](https://proxysql.com/Documentation/global-variables/mysql-variables/)  the `mysql-default_query_timeout` variable specifies the maximal duration of queries to the backend. Have you tried to increse this timeout value? (Note that the link provided is not supported by Google).

Comment: It's a cluster with 3 nodes, the only pods important to the proxy is the 3 running a php api. I have checked ressources and everything is running as intended. Can you be specific on what part of the setup you want to know more about?